# A word to mean "To murder your colleague"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

`Suicide` is to kill yourself.
`Genocide` is to kill a genus.
`Homicide` is to kill a human.
`Matricide` is to kill one's mother.
`Patricide` is to kill one's father.
`Parricide` is to kill one's close relative.
`Regicide` is to kill a king.
`Uxoricide` is to kill ones wife.

`???` is to kill your colleague?

*Added extras from [Andy's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171755/a-word-to-mean-to-murder-your-colleague/171761?noredirect=1#comment358413_171755)*

Comment: Isn't a colleague a human?

Comment: @Elian, yes, you're right but I want a work to *specifically* mean murdering a co-worker, as opposed to *any* human.

Comment: @Elian P.S.... maybe my colleague isn't a human?

Comment: @Elian Yes, but there are many variations from Latin, e.g. matricide (killing ones mother), regicide (killing a king), uxoricide (killing ones wife).

Comment: OK, three downvotes... what's wrong with the question?

Comment: @Andy Yes, patricide, matricide, fratricide, regicide, infanticide, etc. But the murder of a colleague, employer, or subordinate is referred to simply as a homicide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider *confratricide*.

> [confrere](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confrere): a fellow member of a fraternity or profession; a colleague.
>
> [Middle English, from Old French, from Medieval Latin *confrater*: Latin *con-* con- + *frater* brother

Comment: Perfect, I think.

Comment: @BanksySan Yes, it should fit what you're looking for.:-)

Comment: I think this even works with non-human colleagues, taking the definition and ignoring its derivation.  What do you think?

Comment: @BanksySan You bet it does. Check this out: https://www.temple.edu/tempress/titles/1908_reg.html

Comment: You rock, is there any way I can accept your answer twice? `define both us and our animal confreres`.  Now... being **very** pedantic, they've qualified `confreres` as `animal confreres`. Would that sentence work without the `animal` qualifier?

Comment: @BanksySan Grammatically speaking, it would. The only thing is that "colleague," "confrere," "coworker," "associate," etc., are terms that typically apply to humans, not to animals. And so, the qualifier helps in that it makes the sentence unequivocal to the reader.

Answer (score 5):

In military terms when a unit on your side kills someone on your side it is called **fratricide** from the Latin word for brother.

Comment: I like that suggestion.

Comment: Now in the military it is usually the case that it is an unintended result...manslaughter rather than murder.

Comment: Then a brother in pens, pencils, and stupid forms!

Comment: I'm not sure if _fratricide_ is still used. Terms like _friendly-fire_ seem to be more popular nowadays.

Comment: I don't think that would work in this case.  In the military it is not unusual to refer to your (living) colleagues as "brothers", but it is less common outside of a military organization.  +1 anyway

Answer (score 3):

There is no word for murders so specific as a nurse killing *young healthy patients who are hospitalized for surgery*, or the *murder of a homeless man.* What is the word for murder committed during terroristic acts? It is called *homicide* or *murder*.

Perhaps the closest answer to your specific query is [**going postal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_postal):

> Going postal, in American English slang, means becoming extremely and uncontrollably angry, often to the point of violence, usually in a workplace environment.
>
> The expression derives from a series of incidents from 1983 onward in which United States Postal Service (USPS) workers **shot and killed managers, fellow workers**, and members of the police or general public in acts of mass murder. Between 1986 and 1997, more than 40 people were gunned down by spree killers in at least 20 incidents of workplace rage.

Edmond, Oklahoma in 1986

> On August 20, 1986, 14 employees were shot and killed and six wounded at the Edmond, Oklahoma, post office by Patrick Sherrill, a postman who then committed suicide with a shot to the forehead. This incident is believed to have coined the term **"going postal"**.

December 31, 1993 in Los Angeles Times:

> ...the more deadly mass shootings around the nation, which have lent a new term to the language, referring to shooting up the office as "going postal".

Comment: Note the question is about the act itself, not about the emotions and/or mental state of the actor.

Answer (score 2):

Colleague in the 'friend' sense:

[**Amicicide**](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/48493/amicicide): Men who have been the firmest friends, while in each others company periodically and frequently, have clashed and quarrelled in their attempt to dwell beneath the same roof, and, occupying the same apartments, have been moved to commit amicicide.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a common term used for it, but given the method for creating these words, take the Latin word for colleague:

> colleague -> collega, collegae, n.

Take the root, **colleg** and add ***-icide***, to get ***collegicide***.

Comment: That sounds like killing a college, and what a good idea.

Comment: Great, now I'm on some list somewhere by association.

Comment: This is actually correct: colleague => collega (a feminine noun, rather like *nauta*) but as Oldcat has pointed out, maybe something is lost in translation.

Comment: @AndrewLeach minor correction: Collega, collegae is a first declension noun, but it is a neuter/common gender word. It just appears feminine because first declension is typically feminine. However, first declension nouns describing a role not specifically ascribed to women is usually either masculine or neuter.

Comment: @AndrewLeach And actually, *nauta, nautae* is a masculine noun.

Comment: @Andy Yes, first declension noun with feminine endings and all. When I was learning Latin (a **very** long time ago, which might excuse some of the rustiness and slapdash comments) I was rather childishly amused that something like *sailor* was treated as a feminine noun.

Answer (score 1):

A military term for killing your fellow soldiers, particularly a commanding officer, is **[fragging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragging)** (from fragmentation grenade).

> The term now encompasses any means of deliberately and directly causing the death of fellow military members.