# Single word to change groups

Tags: single-word-requests

In a table top RPG there exists a spell which forces the target to do what is commanded but the word count available is one. For example, "Rampage" would cause the target to see everyone as a foe. Also, "Cower" causes the target to go into the fetal position.

I am looking to turn one target into my personal bodyguard, or ally with a single word. In the example "Attack" would not work because it would require a second word as a target, like "Attack them" or "Attack humans".

Is there a single word that effectively states a "180 degree change in view" (morally) or to state "your enemies are my enemies"?

Comment: A zillion years ago I was in the same position myself. We, uh, mislead the DM with a command of "turncoat," which is a single word, although not actually a verb.

Comment: If the limit really is "single word" rather than an upper limit on number of charcters, you could use "CamelCase" for things like ***AttackHumans***. But assuming it's contextually obvious that your "target" was originally an ***enemy***, you could perhaps consider commanding him to ***Defect**!*

Comment: Not that I am aware of; however, you may find assistance with the **Command** spell at [The RPG Stack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+command)

Comment: @FumbleFingers the "CamalCase" example is to far out there, but there is not limit on the number of characters available for the word. although, "Defect" is a good start and could work given the situation.

Comment: [Related post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/171755/216106) suggesting *fratricide* and *confratricide* for killing your colleague(s).

Comment: @Davo "confratricide" has the potential of being a great answer, unfortunately it is not an established word nor is it an action.

Comment: @reed and so it's a comment linking to a related question, and not an answer.

Comment: Does it have to be English?  Some languages already come dangerously close to the CamelCase approach with their compound words (I'm looking at you, German).  Otherwise it'll be fairly hard to target a specific third party, as most verbs you'd use for that in English would expect a subject.     (p.s.: mutiny?)

Comment: This is very much a 'be careful what you wish for' situation.  The spellcaster must be especially careful not to swear out loud when she sees her initial command not turning out as planned...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Defect!* might work:

> 1 : to forsake one cause, party, or nation for another often because of a change in ideology
>   // a former KGB agent who *defected* to America

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defect))</sub>

and another verb which conveys the same idea is *to renegade*:

> : to become a renegade (a deserter from one faith, cause, or allegiance to another)

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renegade))</sub>

but I'm not sure if this can actually be used in imperative form.

---

Of course, your Game Master is free to have the enemy interpret either option as taking the sides of *another* (third) party.

Comment: "Of course, your Game Master is free to have the enemy interpret either option as taking the sides of another (third) party." Or drop their arms entirely, since renegading from one side could mean simply doing nothing more to aid that side.

Comment: How about *renege* as the imperative? It literally means going back on a promise, but game words like these are often very metaphoric

Comment: The word has to be understandable to the target. Personally, if someone told me to renegade, I wouldn't understand that as I'm not aware of its use as a verb so the spell would fail.

Answer (score 6):

The trickiness here is that you're asking for a verb to do two distinct functions:

1. Be your ally.
2. Be their enemy.

1 is especially tricky because customarily English would use a grammatical object to signal who should be allied. Omitting the direct object from "Befriend me," "Guard me," and "Protect me" would either lead to ambiguity ("Befriend" and "Protect" could default to a number of targets) or a less productive action ("Guard" - the target would take a defensive stance).

However, if you wanted (2) the target to oppose their masters (so "their enemies would be your enemies"), try **revolt**. It is intransitive. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolt?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld):

> : to renounce allegiance or subjection (as to a government) : REBEL

And here's the also-good choice of **[rebel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebel)**:

> : to renounce and resist by force the authority of one's government

In other words, **to revolt** or **to rebel** have a strong sense of using violence ("resist by force") against the people one once owed allegiance to. That sense is strong enough that a "[bloodless revolution](https://www.britannica.com/event/Glorious-Revolution)" is a remarkable event. A character who took that command and didn't attack their former soldiers or leaders would be taking an unusual step.

Answer (score 1):

Betray
Convert
Realign
Turn
Forsake
Spurn
Revolt

All these basically mean leave one side and join another.

Comment: These are good words, but they are too ambiguous for the context given.

Comment: This could be a solid answer, but its at the moment it is just a smattering of words. I would take the time and do something similar to what the other two answers have.